# MySQL query not returning the expected number of rows when using 2 Inner joins

Tags: mysql

having some trouble with a query and im hoping you all can help my see what im missing.
There are three rows in COLLECTIONS that have the value of 1 for album.  But for whatever reason the query is only returning 1 row instead of 3.

Any Ideas?

```
SELECT a.id assetID
     , a.uri
     , a.caption
     , u.alias
     , u.icon
     , u.link
     , u.id userID
  FROM collections c
  JOIN assets a
    ON a.id = c.asset 
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = a.user 
 WHERE c.album = 1
 ORDER 
    BY a.ts DESC
```

Heres the data structure

COLLECTIONS

```
album   asset
1       1
2       2
1       3
1       4
2       5
```

ASSETS

```
id  uri                         user    private new ts          type    caption
1   1-1391997727-15835000.jpg   1       public  0   1368847153  image   this is a test file thingy
2   2-1391997760-42134600.jpg   1       public  0   1368847353  image   more test files WOOHOO  0   0
3   3-1391997811-96846600.jpg   3       public  0   1368847553  image   i took this picture wooo         
4   3-1391997840-97233100.jpg   3       public  0   1368848232  image            
5   3-1391997859-93753900.jpg   3       public  0   1368848781  image   w00t
```

USERS

```
id  alias       link    icon
1   dbunting    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Your query as written is correctly returning only 1 row. My question is, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: And change WHERE to AND

Comment: If you change `WHERE` to `AND` you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: @ragol I'd like to see the sqlfiddle for that padawan

Comment: @Strawberry: I won't bother. :) An `AND` is a logical operator. You can combine two expressions with it in a JOIN, but then you'll have to use parenthesis. Otherwise it's a syntax error.

Comment: @ragol No. It isn't. But keep up the good work

Comment: WHERE a.album=1 is actually WHERE assets.album=1   ... does table assets have a column "album" ?

Comment: The OP didn't answer my question. He still didn't tell us what it is he really wants to achieve.

Comment: @aconrad - that was my editing error...

Comment: Im trying to return the requested data for everything referenced in COLLECTIONS

Comment: Yes. Change your INNER JOINs to LEFT [OUTER} JOINs

Comment: OK, ill give that a shot.  Ive used the above style in the past and gotten the results i expected, but its been years (so rusty)

Comment: changed INNER JOIN to LEFT OUTER JOIN and it works.  Strawberry youre my new hero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a single row in the resultset because there is a single matched row in table assets for user id 1.

This is a good link for how joins work: [What is the difference between Left, Right, Outer and Inner Joins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins)

This query:

```
SELECT 
c.album,
    a.id assetID
     , a.uri
     , a.caption
     , u.alias
     , u.icon
     , u.link
     , u.id userID
  FROM collections c
  INNER JOIN assets a ON (a.id = c.asset AND c.album=1)
  LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = a.user
```

This will output the 3 rows for album 1

Play with it at: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00b0f/1